# Is there a Java framework that implements a simple flexible multipurpose comparator that will work with Java 1.7

Tags: java, sorting, frameworks, java-7

A number of times I have needed to sort lists of objects based on different fields and I have ended up writing a comparator that uses reflection to sort the list based on a given method or methods.  Is there a framework that already implements something like this?  Is there something in Java that already implements this?  (I searched java comparator framework in SO and came up with 35 hits that did not seem to address this).

Something like this:

A Comparator to compare things based on a given method or methods:

```
package org.myframework.util.comparator;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    //
    // instance variables
    //

    private ArrayList<Method> methods;

    //
    // constructors
    //

    public SimpleComparator() {
        this.methods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    }

    //
    // trivial getters and setters
    //

    public ArrayList<Method> getMethods() {
        return methods;
    }

    public void setMethods(ArrayList<Method> methods) {
        this.methods = methods;
    }

    //
    // implementation of compare
    //

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        for (Method method : this.methods) {
            int diff = this.compare(o1, o2, method);
            if (diff != 0) {
                return diff;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int compare(Object o1, Object o2, Method method) {
        try {
            Object[] args = {};
            Comparable value1 = (Comparable) method.invoke(o1, args);
            Comparable value2 = (Comparable) method.invoke(o2, args);
            if (value1 == null && value2 == null) {
                return 0;
            } else if (value1 == null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (value2 == null) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return value1.compareTo(value2);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Class<T> cls, String methodName) {
        try {
            SimpleComparator comp = new SimpleComparator();
            Class[] parameterTypes = {};
            Method method = cls.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
            comp.getMethods().add(method);
            Collections.sort(list, comp);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Class<T> cls, String[] methodNames) {
        try {
            SimpleComparator comp = new SimpleComparator();
            Class[] parameterTypes = {};
            for(String methodName : methodNames) {
                Method method = cls.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
                comp.getMethods().add(method);
            }
            Collections.sort(list, comp);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

}
```

An example Thing class for things that can be sorted:

```
package org.myframework.util.comparator;

public class Thing {

    //
    // instance variables
    //

    private String name;

    private String color;

    private String hue;

    private int number;

    private float cost;

    //
    // constructor
    //

    public Thing(String name, String color, String hue, int number, float cost) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.hue = hue;
        this.number = number;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    //
    // trivial getters and setters
    //

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getHue() {
        return hue;
    }

    public void setHue(String hue) {
        this.hue = hue;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public float getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(float cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

}
```

An example of what I would like to be able to do:

```
package org.myframework.util.comparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing thing1 = new Thing("thing1", "red  ", null, 1, 1.00f);
        Thing thing2 = new Thing("thing2", "green", null, 2, 100.00f);
        Thing thing3 = new Thing("thing3", "orange", null, 3, 3.00f);
        Thing thing4 = new Thing("thing4", "yellow", null, 4, 4.00f);
        Thing thing5 = new Thing("thing5", "red  ", "pink", 5, 5.00f);
        Thing thing6 = new Thing("thing6", "red  ", "maroon", 6, 6.00f);
        Thing thing7 = new Thing("thing7", "red  ", "candy", 7, 7.00f);
        Thing thing8 = new Thing("thing8", "red  ", "fire", 8, 8.00f);
        ArrayList<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
        things.add(thing2);
        things.add(thing4);
        things.add(thing6);
        things.add(thing8);
        things.add(thing7);
        things.add(thing5);
        things.add(thing3);
        things.add(thing1);
        // the unsorted list
        System.out.println("\n\nBefore sort:");
        showList(things);
        // sort by name
        SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, "getName");
        System.out.println("\n\nSorted by name:");
        showList(things);
        // sort by color
        SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, "getColor");
        System.out.println("\n\nSorted by color:");
        showList(things);
        // sort by hue
        SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, "getHue");
        System.out.println("\n\nSorted by hue:");
        showList(things);
        // sort by color and hue
        String[] colorAndHue = { "getColor", "getHue" };
        SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, colorAndHue);
        System.out.println("\n\nSorted by color and hue:");
        showList(things);
        // sort by cost
        SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, "getCost");
        System.out.println("\n\nSorted by cost:");
        showList(things);
    }

    private static void showList(List<Thing> things) {
        for (Thing thing : things) {
            System.out.println(thing.getName() + "\t" + thing.getColor() + "\t" + thing.getHue() + "\t" + thing.getNumber() + "\t" + thing.getCost());
        }
    }

}
```

Output from this example:

```
Before sort:
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing1  red     null    1   1.0


Sorted by name:
thing1  red     null    1   1.0
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0


Sorted by color:
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing1  red     null    1   1.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0


Sorted by hue:
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing1  red     null    1   1.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0


Sorted by color and hue:
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing1  red     null    1   1.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0


Sorted by cost:
thing1  red     null    1   1.0
thing3  orange  null    3   3.0
thing4  yellow  null    4   4.0
thing5  red     pink    5   5.0
thing6  red     maroon  6   6.0
thing7  red     candy   7   7.0
thing8  red     fire    8   8.0
thing2  green   null    2   100.0
```

Comment: Why won't you create a comparator for each property and then sort? NameComparator, ColorComparator.

Comment: Because I don't want to have to create a whole new comparator class for every class/field combination I would like to sort on.  If I wanted to allow a user to specify any combination of sorts for the Thing object I would need to create a NameComparator, NameColorComparator, NameHueComparator, NameColorHueComparator, HueColorNameComparator, etc.  Using the SimpleComparator class above I can sort on any combination of fields using a single line of code: for example, this line in the above Example class SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, colorAndHue);

Comment: You can use factory method to get the required comparator. SimpleComparator.sort(things, Thing.class, factory.getComparator(colorAndHue));

Comment: I would still need to write all of the comparators that would be returned by the factory (getComparator) method.  With the above SimpleComparator class I'm only writing one comparator.

Answer (score 5):

From the examples you provide, seems like using [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) in Java 8 and passing a method reference would be a solution.

**EDIT:** Adding simple example after OP request

```
Collections.sort(Comparator.comparing(Thing::getHue));
```

Comment: For many cases passing in a method reference works nicely and in those where it doesn't a small lambda often does the trick.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what that would look like?

Comment: Edited answer with simple example (taken almost directly from referenced API docs)

Comment: Looks like a great addition for Java 8. Unfortunately I'm on Java 7